# SQL to count number of partitions that has statistics and with missing statistics

Tags: oracle, count, analytics

I am on Oracle11g.
For each table, I want to check the number of partitions that has been analyzed and the number of partitions that has not been analyzed.
At the moment, I am using the SQL below:

```
COMPUTE SUM OF "UNANALYZED" ON REPORT
COMPUTE SUM OF "ANALYZED" ON REPORT
COMPUTE SUM OF "TOTAL" ON REPORT
BREAK ON REPORT
select t1.table_name, 
       decode(t2.unanalyzed,null,0,t2.unanalyzed) unanalyzed,
       decode(t3.analyzed,null,0,t3.analyzed) analyzed,
       t1.total
from 
      ( SELECT table_name, count(1) total
        FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS p
        WHERE 1=1
        AND table_owner = 'ABC'
        GROUP BY table_name ) t1 ,
      ( SELECT table_name, count(1) unanalyzed
        FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS p
        WHERE 1=1
        AND table_owner = 'ABC'
        AND last_analyzed is NULL 
        GROUP BY table_name ) t2 ,
      ( SELECT table_name, count(1) analyzed
        FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS p
        WHERE 1=1
        AND table_owner = 'ABC'
        AND last_analyzed is NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY table_name ) t3
where t1.table_name = t2.table_name (+)
      and t1.table_name = t3.table_name (+)
order by t1.table_name
;
```

It is working like I would have wanted it to.
I just want to know if there is alternative to this SQL that will give the same result?
Something shorter or simpler maybe or something that uses analytic function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that :

```
SELECT
    table_owner,
    table_name,
    SUM(DECODE(last_analyzed, NULL, 1, 0)) AS unanalyzed,
    SUM(DECODE(last_analyzed, NULL, 0, 1)) AS analyzed,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM
    dba_tab_partitions
WHERE 
    table_owner = 'ABC'
GROUP BY
    table_owner,
    table_name;
```

Ps: I kept your logic, but if last_analysed was 5 years ago, is it really analysed ?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I never thought of using SUM, no wonder I can't get the right numbers that I am expecting before :(

About your Ps:
"Ps: I kept your logic, but if last_analysed was 5 years ago, is it really analysed ?"
Do you mean to consider last_analyzed from 5 years ago as unanalyzed, so change

   DECODE(last_analyzed, NULL, 1, 0)

to something like

   DECODE(last_analyzed, NULL, 1, <[5-yrs-ago],1,0)

I am using this on Oracle and I believe I can total using compute sum and break on report. Is there a way to do the totals without using compute?